# When Compiling VB Code with Roslyn where do I get reference?

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

I want to be able to compile a single VB.Net file with Roslyn, every example I have found has different ways to get References, using different API's and none of them will compile every program I feed into my application. Below are just some of the ways I have found to get references. I don't understand what is actually required to compile a program error free. Some program have imports, do I need to pass the DLL's being referenced to the compiler? How to I find them what about NuGet Reference? Some of the examples below (Like including CodeAnalysisReference) give me more errors than not using any. I don't want to run the file being compiled, I just want to get Diagnostics errors. Is there any documentation that explains how reference passed to Roslyn work and what needs to be passed?

```
Dim CodeAnalysisReference As MetadataReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(Compilation).Assembly.Location)
Dim VisualBasicSymbolsReference As MetadataReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(VisualBasicCompilation).Assembly.Location)
Dim runtimePath As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\{0}.dll"
Dim DefaultReferences As IEnumerable(Of MetadataReference) = {
        CodeAnalysisReference,
        VisualBasicSymbolsReference,
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(String.Format(runtimePath, "System")),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(String.Format(runtimePath, "System.Core"))
    }

Dim ActionReferences As MetadataReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(Action).Assembly.Location())
Dim ComponentModelReferences As MetadataReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute).Assembly.Location())
Dim CorlibReference As MetadataReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(Object).Assembly.Location)
Dim EnumerableReferences As MetadataReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(Enumerable).Assembly.Location())
Dim MSCorLib As MetadataReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(String.Format(runtimePath, "mscorlib"))
Dim systemReference As PortableExecutableReference = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(Function(x As Reflection.Assembly) String.Equals(x.GetName().Name, NameOf(System), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(Function(a As Reflection.Assembly) MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(a.Location)).Single()
Dim vbRuntime As PortableExecutableReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(CompilerServices.StandardModuleAttribute).Assembly.Location)

Dim references() As MetadataReference = {ActionReferences, ComponentModelReferences, CorlibReference, EnumerableReferences, MSCorLib, systemReference, vbRuntime}
```

Comment: Does the VB.NET file come from a vbproj project?

Comment: Not really, I have a csproj that the VB code was translated from.